# 301 redirect on URL without parameter

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I am wondering if it is possible to remove a URL parameter (meaning to redirect to the version of the URL without that parameter) from the URL **wherever** it is in the URL. Meaning it doesn't necessarily have to be at the end. Its a global parameter, so multiple URLS are affected.

Examples:

```
www.example.com/example.html?sale=1 301 -> www.example.com/example.html
www.example.com/example.html?sale=1&color=black 301 -> ww.example.com/example.html&color=black
```

etc.

Comment: Could i know why u want that? Why not just ignoring the value in the application?

Comment: Can you please show your .htaccess file. What you already made?

Comment: It was some parameters in my old e-commerce that have been indexed in huge numbers by Google. I'd like them to be de-indexed, but with passing the value (if they have any) to the original URL.

Comment: Exactly what i thought. Maybe its a better idea to make a canonical link instead? With white listed query Params? This will also solve problems not only for sale=1 but for other unwantet get params.

Comment: Actually all the main, proper URL have self referencing canonicals, hence all the params URL also point to that main URL, which is good. But I believe that wont make them disappear from index, will it?

Comment: I have like 10x more pages indexed that are actually there, >200k. I want to cut them as much as possible

Comment: I don't understand all point to the main URL? Google threads cannonicals like 301 but only if you use them for the same content. If you canonical all to one page Google will ignore it.

Comment: I meant that when you go to www.example.com/example.html you will find link rel canonical to www.example.com/example.html. Thanks to that, whatever you will add at the end of the URL like www.example.com/example.html?sale=1 or www.example.com/example.html?whatever=0?sale=1?blabla you will still have rel canonical to www.example.com/example.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two rules to remove the query (key and value) from your urls:

```
RewriteEngine on
#1)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?sale=[1]\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NC,NE,L,R]
#2)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?sale=1&([^\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [NC,NE,L,R]
```

The first rule above redirects the browser from

- example.com/foo/?sale=1

to

- example.com/foo/

and the second rule redirects the browser from :

- example.com/foo/?sale=1&foo=bar

to

- example.com/foo/?foo=bar

Change `R` to `R=301` in both rules when you are sure the redirect is working fine.

Comment: Unfortunetely it does not work, no redirection is applied

Comment: @caipi This code is working fine on my apache searver. Make sure this is the very first rule in your htaccess and there are no othere conflicting rules

Comment: Hmm strange. I am trying this: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sale= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1? [R=301,L] - this will effectively redirect to the main URL if the sale parameter is found regardless where in URL? This will boost my main URL SEO